# bash: sort strings according to the alphabetical order

Tags: bash

```
for f in "$blocks"/*.png; do
img_name=$(basename "${f}")
img_name="${img_name/.png/}"
printf "!["$img_name"](%s)\n\n" "$f"
done > output
```

This shell script loop png images located in the same folder, take the name of each fime and then create an output file with the following format for each PNG separated by empty line:

```
![name_of_the_image](full_path_to_the_image)
```

I need to sort the strings in the output according to the alphabetical order of the looped file_names, via piping the printf to some external command.

Comment: Don't you mean `'[%s](%s)\n\n' "$img_name" "$f"`?

Comment: BTW, `*.png` _already_ sorts in your active `LC_COLLATE` order. You don't need to do anything else.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't even think about that when answering. We clearly do not have the full picture here :-)

Comment: BTW, if you give `basename` a second argument, it's the extension to remove. So you can use `img_name=$(basename "$f" .png)`

Comment: Err, you mean by changing `> output` into `| sort > output`?

Comment: OP has given no new information in almost a day regarding this sorting business. The question seems abandoned.